# Geopandas : displaying several layers on iPython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython, geopandas

I'm testing geopandas library for a simple exercise : displaying several points on a map, and then superimpose a large circle above to delete a part of them [with the difference method](http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html).

To check that the transformation works fine, I'm using an iPython notebook to see my different layers.

So, here's the begining of my manipulation :

```
%matplotlib inline
# this line is just for a correct plotting in an iPython nb
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Point

df = pd.read_csv("historical_monuments.csv", sep = ",")
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(fichier.Longitude, fichier.Latitude)]
# I convert two columns of my csv for geographic information displaying
df = df.drop(['Longitude', 'Latitude'], axis = 1)
# just delete two columns of my first df to avoid redundancy
geodf = gp.GeoDataFrame(file, crs=None, geometry=geometry)
```

Then, to see my points, I just wrote :

```
geodf.plot(marker='o', color='red', markersize=5)
```

Here's the result :

[image]

That's super fine. Now I just want to add in this layer a point with a large radius. I tried this :

```
base = gdf.plot(marker='o', color='red', markersize=5)
# the first plotting becomes a variable to reuse it
center_coord = [Point(6.18, 48.696000)]
center = gp.GeoDataFrame(crs=None, geometry=center_coord)
circle = center.buffer(0.001)
```

Then, I just thought that these command would be enough :

```
circle.plot(ax=base, color = 'white')
```

But instead of a graphical displaying, my notebook returns :

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f763bdde5c0>
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f763be5ef60>
```

And I didn't find what could be wrong so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my best guess is you didn't execute your code within one Cell... for some strange behaviour the plot does not show up if executed over multiple cells... I could replicate your problem, however when i executed the Code in one cell the plot showed up.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Create Fake Data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,20,size=(10, 3)), columns=['Longitude','Latitude','data'])

# create Geometry series with lat / longitude
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)]

df = df.drop(['Longitude', 'Latitude'], axis = 1)

# Create GeoDataFrame
geodf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=None, geometry=geometry)


# Create Matplotlib figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Set Axes to equal (otherwise plot looks weird)
ax.set_aspect('equal')


# Plot GeoDataFrame on Axis ax
geodf.plot(ax=ax,marker='o', color='red', markersize=5)
# Create new point
center_coord = [Point(15, 13)]
center = gp.GeoDataFrame(crs=None, geometry=center_coord)
# Plot new point
center.plot(ax=ax,color = 'blue',markersize=5)
# Buffer point and plot it
circle = center.buffer(10)
circle.plot(color = 'white',ax=ax)
```

[image: Final plot]

ps: Btw you've got some variables mixed up

Comment: Hello schlump and many thanks for your answer. Just tested the solution, but got a _NameError: name 'plt' is not defined_ for plt.subplots()... What module I missed ? EDIT : works fine anyway !

Comment: Oh yeha that was my fault sry forgot to add "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
%matplotlib inline
```

produces a static plot. Once it appears in your notebook it can not be changed anymore. That is why you have to put your code in a single Cell as schlump said.

An alternative would be to switch to the notebook backend, which is interactive and allows you to modify your plot over several Cells. To active it simply use

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

instead of inline.